# Php errors with localization translate

Tags: php, localization, translation

Hello i tried to do translate to my website with localization
with this code:

```
    $locale = "he_IL.UTF-8";
    $domain = "./locale";

    putenv("LANG=$locale");
    putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
```

and i got error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES'
Deprecated: setlocale(): Passing locale category name as string is deprecated. Use the LC_* -constants instead in
Warning: setlocale(): Invalid locale category name LC_MESSAGES, must be one of LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, or LC_TIME in
```

and the language dont working...
i tried to set:

```
 if (!defined('LC_MESSAGES'))
     define('LC_MESSAGES', 6);
```

its solve the errors but still the lagnauge dont translated...
i using wamp for this website,
but in web server its working good the translate... only in the wamp not

tnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP Manual entry for setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

> LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)

We can assume therefore that your webserver has a version of PHP compiled with libintl, but that your WAMP server does not. My understanding is that LC_MESSAGES doesn't work very well on Windows.

Try instead using:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL=$locale);
```

If you're [using php-gettext](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/) then make sure you've installed your locales to the appropriate folders.